# Why there is no data race in this example using if statements?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am reading  Bjarne's FAQ on [Memory Model](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#gc-abi), here is a quote

> So, C++11 guarantees that no such problems occur for "separate memory locations.'' More precisely: A memory location cannot be safely accessed by two threads without some form of locking unless they are both read accesses. Note that different bitfields within a single word are not separate memory locations, so don't share structs with bitfields among threads without some form of locking. Apart from that caveat, the C++ memory model is simply "as everyone would expect.''

> However, it is not always easy to think straight about low-level concurrency issues. Consider:
>
> ```cpp
> // start with x==0 and y==0
>   
> if (x) y = 1; // Thread 1 
>
> if (y) x = 1; // Thread 2
> ```
>
> Is there a problem here? More precisely, is there a data race? (No there isn't).

My question is, why there is no data race? It is obvious to me that there apparently is a data race since thread 1 is a writer for `y` while thread 2 is a reader for `y`, and similarly for `x`.

Comment: starting with (0,0) is the keypoint here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` and `y` are `0` and therefore the code behind the `if` will not be executed and there will be no write and therefore there can be no data race.

Comment: So what's the point of Bjarne's example? Looks fairly trivial to me but he writes it as if there is a hidden issue...

Comment: @zett42 I had to read it like 10 times before I got it and the OP had to ask on SO to get it. The point is that even this extremely simple example can get people confused. Maybe it was just a bit too simple to confuse you, but the general point that reasoning about thread-safety is difficult still stands.

Comment: It only confused me because he wrote `it is not always easy to think straight` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The critical point is:

> start with `x==0` and `y==0`

Since both variables are set to `0` when it starts, the `if` tests will fail, and assignments will never occur. So both threads are only reading the variables, never writing them.